# EntityFramework Core 2.1 linq query with DateTime.Add() in where clause not translated into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have the need to combine two DateTime values from two columns to one datetime-value. The first holds the date-part and the seconds hold the time-part. Now I want to take the date and add the time to it so I can use it to properly filter it against a parameter.

My problem here is, that I cannot get the combination to get translated to SQL and therefore executed on the SQL-Server rather than the client.

What I have tried so far:
In the following "ColumnA" is the first column with the date-part value and "ColumnB" is the second column with the time-part in it. "DateParameter "is the injected parameter to check against.

```
1) .Where(a => (a.ColumnA.Date + a.ColumnB.TimeOfDay) <= DateParameter);
```

```
2) .Where(a => (a.ColumnA.Date.Add(a.ColumnB.TimeOfDay)) <= DateParameter);
```

```
3) .Where(a => (a.ColumnA.Date.AddHours(a.ColumnB.Hour).AddMinutes(a.ColumnB.Minute).AddSeconds(a.ColumnB.Second)) <= DateParameter);
```

```
4) .Where(a => (new DateTime(a.ColumnA.Year, a.ColumnA.Month, a.ColumnA.Day, a.ColumnB.Hour, a.ColumnB.Minute, a.ColumnB.Second)) <= DateParameter);
```

I am running on EntityFramework Core 2.1 on .NetFramework4.7.2.
All of the above actually executes (cannot translate exception is from version 3.0 or 3.1) but does all the filtering in RAM instead of on the SQL-Server.

The Function ".AddDays()" gets properly translated, ".AddHours()" does not, why is this? Both could be translated into the DATEADD()-Function just with different parameters for "datepart".

Comment: (3) works for me (EF Core 3.1.3, SqlServer)

Comment: EF Core 2.1 won't be getting any enhancements, so you will have to work with what is supported - bugs are still being fixed for `DateTime` in EF Core 3.1.

Comment: Upgraded to EF Core 3.1.4. Now I am getting exception that some parts are not supported or the query could not be fully translated and i should explicitly switch to client-evaluation. Specifically the datepart-value 'hour' is not supported which is the SQL equivalent of "DateTime.AddHour()".